# Command 'reload' raised an exception: TypeError: BotBase.reload_extension() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Me and my girlfriend have a discord.py 2.0 bot that does "x" things, and I added a command to reload all the extensions. But when executing the same command, it returns the following error:

`Hybrid command raised an error: Command 'reload' raised an exception: TypeError: BotBase.reload_extension() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Here is the code:

reload.py:

```
import discord
import settings

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.interactions import Interaction

@commands.hybrid_command(name="reload", description="Reloads all extensions")
async def reload(ctx):
     for cmd_file in settings.CMDS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
            if cmd_file.name != "__init__.py":
                extensions = f"extension.{cmd_file.name[:-3]}"
                await commands.Bot.reload_extension(name=extensions)
                print(f"Reloaded extension: {extensions}")

async def setup(bot):
    bot.add_command(reload)
```

On the main.py file, it loads the extensions with the following code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
        print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            print(f"Bot is in {guild.name} with {guild.member_count} members")
        bot.remove_command('help')
        for cmd_file in settings.CMDS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
            if cmd_file.name != "__init__.py":
                extensions = f"extension.{cmd_file.name[:-3]}"
                await bot.load_extension(extensions)
                print(f"Loaded extension: {extensions}")
        try:
            synced = await bot.tree.sync()
            print(f"Synced {len(synced)} slash commands\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to sync slash commands: {e}")
```

What it was expected to do:
reloads all the commands/extensions.

What I received as a response:
`Hybrid command raised an error: Command 'reload' raised an exception: TypeError: BotBase.reload_extension() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `commands.Bot` is a class, you need to use the instance (which you defined in your main file).
Since you don't have access directly to your bot instance, you can use `ctx.bot` to access it:

```py
import discord
import settings

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.interactions import Interaction

@commands.hybrid_command(name="reload", description="Reloads all extensions")
async def reload(ctx):
    for cmd_file in settings.CMDS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
        if cmd_file.name != "__init__.py":
            extensions = f"extension.{cmd_file.name[:-3]}"
            await ctx.bot.reload_extension(name=extensions)
            print(f"Reloaded extension: {extensions}")

async def setup(bot):
    bot.add_command(reload)
```

Answer (score 0):

`commands.Bot` is the class.  You need to use an object of that class, and that's what your global `bot` is.  So,

```
await bot.reload_extension(name=extensions)
```